# Compress Png Files missing from build settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

I am building an app which has quite a few images in, therefore I have crushed them all using ImageOptim to help decrease the size of my .IPA. How ever the size of my app has not changed at all.

I have looked on their website and they say to turn off `Compress Png Files` in the Build Settings under Packaging. However that option is not there. I have tried manually adding it into my project.pbxproj but it gets listed under the User Defined section and does not turn it off.

[image: Screenshot of Packaging in Build Settings]

I have also tried searching in the Build settings (My main target is selected).

[image]

So my question is... how can I add `Compress Png Files` into my build settings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It might sound mind blowing, but please read it to the very end.

1. Try dragging and dropping a dummy png file to your project
   navigator, then select like "Add, Copy if Needed" and the option
   will appear in the Packaging section. But, I guess, this is not your case.
2. It looks like you have all your png's contained in an asset catalog rather that just lying around. For that case, I guess, you might want to play around with this:
   [image]

Comment: It's funny that if you delete the dummy png, the "Compress PNG Files" option disappers :)

Comment: This answer saved me. It makes no sense that I need to include a dummy PNG in the project, but that is what worked. XCode 7.3.1

Answer (score 8):

You need to Just Search in Build Setting `png` And CopyPNG File - Packaging is Searched And The Section Have Option is `Compress Png File` is The Default value is `Yes` You will change value `NO` it Means your png Files is Compressed Bellow is the Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: you have also tried searching in the Build settings Just "png" ,Some times it's not Display in General targate,type "png"

Comment: Yes, there are no results for 'png'

Comment: it's really strange, Bcoz i am trying to Search my All Projects Compress Png Option is Available

Comment: These options don't show up if the project's Resources folder doesn't contain a PNG child directly. XCode 7.3.1 ... this is why some projects have PNG and have this bug, but you cannot turn it off or find it by searching for "PNG" in build settings.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the path of the file has been removed or relocated 
you can remove it from here as well check the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you change the format of the file to png, the error shows up all the time for the assets when you try to use it. It's better to find the original png file or save the file as a png file with an image editor.