# App icon error in MDM iron server

Tags: ios, icons, mdm

In MDM getting error as 
"png file has proprietary extension ofCgBI and is interlaced-this is unsupported"
We regenerated the icons and checked for interlaced option in photoshop also. Still in MDM server facing issue. But the icon is coming properly in devices.
Anyone face the same issue and resolved for MDM server?
Please how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution.In xcode Build settings we have to set Compress option to NO.Refer the below link,
[Compress Png Files missing from build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082838/compress-png-files-missing-from-build-settings)